# Transform a web page with Javascript framework to a static html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, report

Because I need to save a web page as a mht file format for a report function. But, my page is build by a Javascript framework(dojo) and the html source just like this.

```
<div id="main">
  <div width="99%">
    <table id="contents">
      <tr> 
        <td id="con_right"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the same time, I also have a controller to set report html to these DOM object dynamically. But I can not save this page as a mht file. Because "Save as" just base on static HTML.

So, I need help for transform a dynamic DOM object in Javascript to a static HTML page.

PS.
I can include any other Javascript framework. If there is a good and fast solution for transform.

Comment: Do you just want to be able to save the generated source?

Comment: Yes! I want to save dynamic generated source. I can get the DOM object in javascript, but I don't know how to push it to a new page for Save as a mht file.

Comment: If you view generated source from the web developer toolbar in Firefox, it will open a window with the source that you can save from. I'm not sure if that's what you mean by save or if your requirement is that you have to do it programmatically.

Comment: YES! I can see all of the dynamic source in the firebug tool. But I need to save a page as a mht file. This feature only supported by IE browser default, and will save this page with pure static HTML source.

Comment: Because all of the user of this report system does not a web developer. I need a general solution for them. Just like they can save a report page by File/save as in browser menu bar and save it as mht format file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html#exercise1) is an example of how to print out the source for any DOM node - you should be able to use that to print the entire page HTML.

**EDIT:**  You might even be able to do something easier:

```
print(document.body.innerHTML);
```

**EDIT2:**

Since you want the generated html to be a static html page, pretty much the only way you're going to (somewhat) reliably get that is to do it via the server.  Send your htmlified DOM to the back end, and have the callback to a redirect to a newly-generated static page with that html.

The implementation is between you and your back-end software, but it can have the following sort of form:

Front-end:

```
//define this function somewhere
redirectFunction( { url: '/backend/create-static-page'
                  , params: { html: document.body.innerHtml }
                  } )
```

Back-end:

```
function create_static_page (req, res) {
   res.send(req.html)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ref. But I want to expand all of the dynamic html within DOM object to current static html page for save a mht format file.